# laravel wire : Call two different routes by passing different parameters with same component in livewire

Tags: laravel-livewire

i have a component in which i created 2 methods `ADD(customer id)` and `Update(customeAddress id)`.
In customer model, customer can have more than one addresses.(Has many relationship)

I am getting error when i am trying to call both these methods from one gui page and same components.

Comment: Can you share your source of the model and component? This would help

Comment: what error you're getting...at least

Comment: thanks, @spekulatius and @Prospero, i managed to solve it by making parameters null
`public function mount($customerId = null, $customerAddressId = null)
{

}
route::('add/{customerId}', Manage::class)->name('add');
route::('update/{customerAddressId}', Manage::class)->name('update')`